# Should I use Command to implement a domain derivations in CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I'm using CQRS on an air booking application. one use case is help customer cancel their tickets. But before the acutal cancellation, the customer wants to know the penalty.

The penalty is calculated based on air rules. Some of our provider could calculate the penalty through exposing an web service while the others don't. (They publish some paper explaining the algorithm instead). So I define a domain service

```
public interface AirTicketService {
     //ticket demand method

     MonetaryAmount penalty(String ticketNumber);

     void cancel(String ticketNumber, MonetaryAmount penalty);
}
```

My question is which side(command/query) is responsible for invoking this domain service and returning result in a CQRS style application?

I want to use a Command: CalculatePenlatyCommand, In this way, it's easy to resuse the domain model, but it's a little odd because this command does not modify state.

Or should I retrieve a readmodel of ticket if this is a query? But the same DomainService is needed on both command and query side, it's odd too.

Is domain derivation a query?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to shoehorn everything in to the command-query pipeline. You could query this service independently from the UI without issuing a command or asking the read-model.

Comment: The arg in penalty() needs a ticketNumber given by our provider,  I store this value in AirReservation aggregate and an AirReservation readmodel. So before calling the service, I need to retrieve the domain model from repository or query readmodel. But I will consider your suggestion and +1 for the response and "shoehorn" :)

Comment: I see. In that case you should get the ticket number from the read model, and then query the AirTicketService.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with satisfying a query using an existing model if it "fits" both the terminology and the structure of that model. No need to build up a separate read model for that purpose. It's not without risk, since the semantics and the context of the query should be closely tied to the model that is otherwise used for write purposes only. The risk I allude to is the fact that the write and read concerns could drift apart (and we're back at square one, i.e. the reason why people pick CQRS in the first place). So you must keep paying attention as new requirements come in.

Queries that fit this model really well are what I call "simulators', where you want to run a simulation using current state to e.g. to give feedback to an end user. On more than one occasion I've found that the simulation logic could be reused both as a feedback mechanism and as an execution (of a write operation/command) steering mechanism. The difference is in what we do with the outcome of the simulation. Again, this is not without risk and requires careful judgement.

Answer (score 1):

You may bring arguments that **Calculate Penalty Command** is not odd at all. 
The user asks the system to do something - *command* enough.

You can even have a **Penalty Calculation Requested Event** event in your domain, and it would feel *right*. Because, at some time, you may be interested in, let's say, *unsure* clients, ones that want to cancel tickets but they change their mind every time etc. The calculation may be performed asynchronously, too - you can provide the result (penalty cost) to the user in various ways afterwards...

Or, in some other way: on your *ticket booked* event, store cancellation penalty, too. Then, you can make that value accessible any time, without the need to recompute it... But this may be wrong (?) because penalty would largely depend on time, right (the late you cancel your ticket, the more you pay)?

If all this would like over-complications etc., then I guess I agree with [rmac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18954904/1475331), too :)